# SwiftUI onAppear/onDisappear not working in Xcode 11.7 (11E801a) iOS 13.7

Tags: swiftui

I've already read [this existing thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661962/is-onappear-and-ondisappear-in-a-navigationview-of-a-swiftui-app-behaving-as-exp) on the issue and comments indicate that this is a bug and has been fixed on 11.7, but I'm still running into it on that version.

In summary:

when the app starts, your view **View 1** fires an onAppear.

when I navigate to a child view (**View 2**) using a Navigation Controller , there is no onDisappear fired for **View 1**, but  an onAppear does fire for **View 2**.

When you navigate back to **View 1**, you do not get a onAppear for **View 1** or an onDisappear for (view 2).

Is there a workaround for a reliable way to trigger events when views appear/disappear? Or should I try hopping to the Xcode beta?

Example Code:

```
  import SwiftUI
    
    struct DetailView: View {
        var body: some View {
            Text("Detail view")
            .onAppear(){
                print("DetailView onAppear fired")
            }
            .onDisappear(){
                print("DetailView onDisappear fired")
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Show detail view")
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Master view")
            }
            .onAppear(){
                print("ContentView onAppear fired")
            }
            .onDisappear(){
                print("ContentView onDisappear fired")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: added! fwiw the onDisappear for detailView did fire, so I guess the problem is the onAppear for the contentView only gets fired on initial loading.

Comment: This is just how SwiftUI works. Instead of `onAppear` in the ContentView, you can use `onDisappear` in the DetailView. But if you explain *why* do you need it, you might get a better answer.

Comment: ah ok this is great to know. I thought onAppear would fire every time I returned to the view. I'm using them to manage Firebase Snapshot Listeners. I think knowing that the onDisappear at least works I can solve my problem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have added `onAppear {..}` and `onDisappear {..}` to the **NavigationView** which is still visible/appears in the **DetailView**. I guess, what you are getting is expected behaviour. `onDisappear {..}` will be called only when view go off from screen.

Adding `onAppear {..}` and `onDisappear {..}` to your **Text** view will give the result as you expected.

### Updated ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                Text("Show detail view")
                .onAppear {
                    print("ContentView onAppear fired")
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    print("ContentView onDisappear fired")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Master view")
        }
    }
}
```

### Output of the updated code:

```
ContentView onAppear fired
DetailView onAppear fired
ContentView onDisappear fired
ContentView onAppear fired
DetailView onDisappear fired
```

Thanks! ‍

Comment: this is super helpful and what I needed. Now things work as expected!

Comment: @HelveticaGoodTime Glad it helped you. Please check this, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: OnAppear on a Text element won't work all the time either.