# How to programmatically make a List's editMode inactive when leaving the view with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Given a List view with an EditButton() in there, if the view is being edited (user tapped the Edit button), how can one disable the edit mode programmatically when the user navigates away from the view? (e.g. similar behavior to the Favorites view in the Phone app on the iPhone)

```
struct ContentView2: View {
    @State var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                    Text(fruit)
                }
                .onDelete { _ in
                    print("Delete")
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
        }
        .onDisappear {
            // make List's editMode be .inactive; how?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `.environment` to bind the List's current edit mode with a `@State` property, as shown in this [awesome article](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/add-edit-move-and-drag-and-drop-in-swiftui-list/).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var editMode = EditMode.inactive /// the edit mode

    @State var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                    Text(fruit)
                }
                .onDelete { _ in
                    print("Delete")
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode) /// bind it here!
        }
        .onDisappear {
            editMode = .inactive /// set to inactive
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your `onDisappear` won't be called if you're using a `NavigationLink` to present a new view, because the `NavigationView` that you attached it to won't actually disappear. You should attach it to the `NavigationLink`'s label instead (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63924929/14351818)).

Final code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var editMode = EditMode.inactive /// the edit mode
    @State var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination:  Text("New view!")) {
                    Text("Navigate away")
                        .onDisappear {
                            editMode = .inactive /// set to inactive
                        }
                }
                
                List {
                    ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                        Text(fruit)
                    }
                    .onDelete { _ in
                        print("Delete")
                    }
                }
                .toolbar {
                    EditButton()
                }
                .environment(\.editMode, $editMode) /// bind it here!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

| *Without* `editMode = .inactive` | *With* `editMode = .inactive` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: List stays in edit mode after presenting new view and coming back] | [image: List exits edit mode after presenting new view and coming back] |

Comment: Excellent, thanks. It turns out I had tried something similar but I had added the `.environment(\.editMode, $editMode)` _before_ the toolbar/button which broke the button. Doing the binding after adding the button is the key to happiness. Good to know for future readers.

Comment: @vmallet yep! SwiftUI modifier ordering is very specific