# Memory allocation issue with SwiftUI’s LazyVGrid when displaying media files

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, lazyvgrid

I’m currently working on a SwiftUI application that displays media files in a grid with LazyVGrid on `GalleryView` where there will be 3 media files per row. The media files are loaded from the app's cache and not from the user's `Photos` app. When user scrolls down to see more media data, media files are lazily loaded into memory and the ones hidden from view are not deallocated from memory because LazyVGrid does not have a built-in memory deallocation mechanism. The memory issues become more apparent (`n>10` where `n` is the number of media files) when there exists a large number of images or videos to show on appear of `GalleryView`:

```swift
struct GalleryView: View {
    @Binding var mediaFiles: [Media]
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                let width = geometry.size.width / 3 - 10
                let gridItemLayout = [GridItem(.fixed(width)), GridItem(.fixed(width)), GridItem(.fixed(width))]
                LazyVGrid(columns: gridItemLayout, spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(mediaFiles, id: \.id) { media in
                        if let image = media.image {
                            Image(uiImage: image)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: width)
                        } else if let videoURL = media.videoURL {
                            // Display video thumbnail here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Media: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let creationTime: Date
    var image: UIImage?
    var videoURL: URL?
}
```

I have tried a custom UIKit approach to handle the memory deallocation issue:

```swift
struct CollectionView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UICollectionViewController

    @Binding var mediaFiles: [Media]
    var width: CGFloat

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UICollectionViewController {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width / 3, height: width / 3)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        let collectionViewController = UICollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionViewController.collectionView?.register(MediaCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collectionViewController.collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        return collectionViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UICollectionViewController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.collectionView?.dataSource = context.coordinator
        uiViewController.collectionView?.delegate = context.coordinator
        uiViewController.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
        var parent: CollectionView

        init(_ parent: CollectionView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return parent.mediaFiles.count
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MediaCell
            let media = parent.mediaFiles[indexPath.row]
            if let image = media.image {
                cell.imageView.image = image
            }
            return cell
        }


        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            // Handle selection here
        }
    }
}
```

so that I can use `CollectionView` in place of LazyVGrid in `GalleryView` like this:

```swift
CollectionView(mediaFiles: $mediaFiles, width: width)
    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
    .onAppear {
        model.loadMediaFiles()
        if let lastMediaIndex = mediaFiles.indices.last {
            scrollView.scrollTo(lastMediaIndex, anchor: .bottom)
        }
    }
```

But the custom UIKit code didn't work as expected because `GalleryView` now shows a blank white screen (on either light/dark mode) instead of showing 3 media items per row. I have also tried using List in place of LazyVGrid, or trying [Chris C](https://codewithchris.com/photo-gallery-app-swiftui-part-2/)'s code to optimize the memory complexity of the problem to `O(1)` but neither approach worked. I've also tried to chunk the data into pieces and create rows with more than one image as suggested in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62970626/lazyvgrid-list-lazystacks-dont-release-views-from-memory) by [@baronfac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13640269/baronfac). However, [@baronfac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13640269/baronfac)'s suggestion only optimizes the memory issue by from `n` to `n/3`, which this linear reduction doesn't really change the memory complexity of the problem since it's still `O(n)`.

Is there a simple and intuitive way to deal with this absence of memory deallocation issue with LazyVGrid? If a UIKit implementation is the best approach, could someone help identify what’s wrong with my current UIKit code that’s causing the GalleryView to display a blank screen?

Comment: Pay attention about geometry reader which may not work as you suppose . Try to remove it and use .infinite for CollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why not use `UIViewRepresentable` instead of view controller variant, and use SwiftUI as parent navigation view, where you inject Collection view (`UIView`)?
2. Memory mangement issue is broad here, assuming that ONLY your collection view's cell will be holding `AVAsset`, `UIImage`, `PHAsset` resulting in them getting overwritten every time new cell is resued. With this setup you will only have N realtime instances of assets, where N = number of visible cells.

Now to do this in SwiftUI you can use [onAppear(perform:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onappear(perform:)) & [onDisappear(perform:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/ondisappear(perform:)) view modifiers.

Here is how I would try:

```
struct GalleryItemView: View {
    @Binding var media: Media
    @State var asset: AVAsset? = nil
    
    func loadAssetIfNeeded() {
        guard self.asset == nil else { return nil }
        guard let videoURL = media.videoURL else { return }
        self.asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
    }
    
    func flushAsset() {
        self.asset = nil
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let image = media.image {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: width)
            } else if let asset = self.asset {
                SomeVideoThumbnailView(previwing: asset)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.loadAssetIfNeeded()
        })
        .onDisappear {
            self.flushAsset()
        }
    }
}
```

then just replace this view in your `LazyVGrid`'s `ForEach` like:

```
ForEach($mediaFiles) { $media in
    GalleryItemView(media: $media)
}
```

Now this way assets are loaded and stay live in memory as long as the view is visible.

*NOTE: Both onAppear and onDisappear were known to be buggy in earlier iterations of SwiftUI. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661962/is-onappear-and-ondisappear-in-a-navigationview-of-a-swiftui-app-behaving-as-exp). But it should be more stable by iOS 14+.*

Comment: I tried your onAppear and onDisappear approach for my code, and there seemed to have a slight improvement on the front end for loading assets on GalleryView (arguably still laggy but better than the previous LazyVGrid implementation), however the memory usage on instruments profiling still shows the linear increase of memory when scrolling down GalleryView with no sign of decrease. I'm not sure why it didn't work. Both of my loadAssetIfNeeded and flushAsset logic also handled UIImages instead of just asset so I'm not sure that's the reason it didn't work.

Comment: Apologies for late reply, did you figure this out? If not could you please share minimal reproducible code?

Answer (score 0):

I was just solving this problem a few days ago, and now it’s solved (completely SwiftUI)

1. Preload (detect current id and calculate whether to load more)

***2. Manually release the original memory (this step is very important)
(Use @StateObject and @Published for real feedback)

Code: [Local database load images, but the memory grows infinitely and memory overflow - SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78138473/local-database-load-images-but-the-memory-grows-infinitely-and-memory-overflow/78149953#78149953)